# Get current input field value in Wizard Form Page in React Final Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

Using Wizard form ant trying to understand how to get current input field value in the  `{activePage}`. Can reach input value in `Wizard.js` but stuck on `Index.js` Someone know where I am missing the point?

[image: Edit React Final Form - Wizard Example]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "current input value": the value of the currently active (focussed) field? To what end? Why do you need it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "current input field value". The value of the currently active/focused field? Why do you need it higher up in `Index.js`?

Comment: @ErikR. not active, "current" means text value equal to input field value.  I wan't to use it as css value. e.g. https://codepen.io/duplich/pen/qjYQEZ

Comment: Similar example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wyo526z83k , it would be more convenient to track values from `index.js` As I understood this function `{({ handleSubmit, change, submitting, values, reset }) => (...) ` brings values into scope. Is it possible to call it from `index.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pull your `<Form>` component out to as high as you need the values. They are only available inside `<Form>`.

It's not strictly recommended, but you could also do something like the [Redux Example](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#redux-example) that updates a Redux store with the current form values.

Comment: Thanks, great tool it is, with Redux Example possible to keep values in separate component.